# .fetchone() and .fetchall() giving none type although when printing the output, the required data has been retrieved

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve the id of the last entry to a data base. `id.fetchall()` gives `[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,)]` but `len(id.fetchall()` comes as 0 and when I try to do `id.fetchall[-1]` it says index is out of range. My code is as follows:

```
            self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
            id = self.curs.execute('''SELECT id FROM Addresses''')

            entry = str(id.fetchall()[-1][0]) + str(firstname) + ' ' + str(lastname)
            menu = self.addedrecord['menu']
            menu.add_command(label = entry, command = lambda value = entry: self.selectedrecord.set(value))

            self.statuslabel.grid_forget()
            self.statuslabel.config(text = 'Record Loaded')
            self.statuslabel.grid(row = 20, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, there is not enough information here to solve your problem.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with your problem. Please after the line `id = self.curs.exe...` add just`print(len(id.fetchall())` and `print(id.fetchall[-1])` like you did, and remove everything else.